# dojo.connect in dojox.enhancedGrid plugin IndirectSelection

Tags: javascript, events, dojo, grid

I stumbled about a strange circumstance.

We use dojo AMD Vers. 1.9. in which dojo.connect is replaced by dojo.on

So far all is okay. Now i want to connect an Eventlistener ( Checkbox is Selected) to the IndirectSelection-plugin of my EnhancedGrid. I search for a solution with dojo.on but just find dojo.connect?!

Is that correct? I mean dojo.connect is deprecated generaly in dojo 1.9?

This is the code i find in the dojo-side:

```
dojo.connect(grid.selection, 'onSelected'|'onDeselected', function(rowIndex){...})
```

Reference: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/grid/EnhancedGrid/plugins/IndirectSelection.html#usages

and here's my Code:

```
if(!registry.byId("GraphGrid")){
        grid = new EnhancedGrid({
                    id: 'GraphGrid',
                    store: GraphicStore,
                    query: { ident: "*" },
                    structure: layout,
                    rowSelector: '20px',
                    keepSelection: false,
                    plugins: {
                        indirectSelection: {
                        headerSelector:false, 
                        width:"40px", 
                        styles:"text-align: center;"
                        }}                          
                    },"GridGraphicInMap");

                /*Call startup() to render the grid*/
                grid.startup();

                grid.on("rowClick", function(evt){
                    var idx = evt.rowIndex,
                        item = this.getItem(idx);
                    //  get a value out of the item
                    var value = this.store.getValue(item, "geom");
                    highlightGeometry(value,true);
                });

                dojo.connect(grid.selection, 'onSelected', getSelectedItems);

                }
                else {
                    setTimeout(function(){
                    grid.setStore(GraphicStore);
                    }, 1000);
                }...
```

I tried to change it to dojo.on or grid.selection.on('Selected',getSelectedItems); but it doesn't work. Is in this special Case dojo.connect still the right way to connect?

The code above works fine, theres nothing wrong with it.

Regards, Miriam

Comment: dojo.connect(grid.selection, 'onSelected', function(rowIndex){ 
    console.log(grid.getItem(rowIndex));//If you want to get the selected row
});

Comment: Thanks for your Answer, but i  think you missunderstood me. I mean, everywhere you should use on('myThingy','click',doSomething); In this case you should use the old dojo.connect('myThingy',onClick,doSomething); My question was about the dojo.connect and if it's correct to use it, when its generally Deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dojo.connect it wont affect event triggering. 
And try using your connect in the following manner:

```
 dojo.connect(grid, 'onSelected', getSelectedItems);
```

or 
      dojo.connect(grid, 'onselectionchanged', getSelectedItems);

Please let me know if any of these doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I think i must revise my question. The code above works fine, thats not the Problem. Question is: Why should I use dojo.connect in dojo 1.9 when they say it's deprecated generally and you should use dojo/on for connecting events. It's only in this specific case.

Comment: It doesn't affect your code any way even if you use a deprecated method, its up to you to use dojo.connect or dojo/on. Its like if u have android 3.0 or 4.4 still your latest app will work on your device, similarly connect or on, your method will be called.

I am using dojo v1.9.3 and both connect and on are working fine in my codes.

Comment: Surely you are right. As i say - it works fine for me too. I just wondered why dojo uses in this case the connect instead of on.