# Event handler for checkbox in dojox.enhancedGrid with IndirectSelection

Tags: javascript, events, dojo, grid

I am using dojo 1.9 EnhancedGrid with indirectSelection and trying to call a function
when checkbox is checked or unchecked using dojo.connect as suggested in document but it is not working for me.

dojo.connect(grid.selection, 'onSelected'|'onDeselected', function(rowIdx){alert("I do come here"); });

I have looked through dojo documentation and  many other posts/forum and they all seem to suggest the above method. Here is another post in this forum [dojo.connect in dojox.enhancedGrid plugin IndirectSelection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19515935/dojo-connect-in-dojox-enhancedgrid-plugin-indirectselection) where person was trying to do similar thing but wasn't able to. There was no answer to that question so posting again.

Please advice. I am stuck here.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, someone else has similar question/issue, this was solved by providing grid as the 3rd argument and handler as the 4th.

```
    dojo.connect(grid.selection, 'onSelected', grid, function(rowIdx){
        var rowItem = grid.getItem(rowIdx); 
        // your code here
    });
```